# The lines between boxes are deleted

Tags: tables

i have a table

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}%l -> left, c -> center, r -> right     
        \hline\cellcolor{blue!25}  &\cellcolor{blue!25} &\cellcolor{blue!25} E\cellcolor{blue!25} &\cellcolor{blue!25} H\cellcolor{blue!25} &\cellcolor{blue!25} \_ &\cellcolor{blue!25}T&\cellcolor{blue!25}M&\cellcolor{blue!25}U&\cellcolor{blue!25}N \\
```

[image]

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends to the magnification of the viewer. However, use `\rowcolor` instaed of
the multiple `\cellcolor` for each column.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\rowcolor{blue!25}  & & E & H & \_ & T & M & U & N \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: as I would for the more columns